# include external modal html document

Tags: html

I have quite a lot of pictures I have to make together with a bootstrap modal. The function together with JS is working fine now, but I would like to optimize the code. This is the HTML code.

**HTML**

```
<img id="courseImage" src="/images/thumbs/image1.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="courseModal" class="modal">

      <!-- The Close Button -->
          <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('courseModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

          <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
          <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

          <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
          <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
```

Is there not a way, where I can include some of the html. I tried to do like this, but that is not working.

```
<img id="courseImage" src="/images/thumbs/image1.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/resources/includes/courseModal.html' ?>
```

I am just thinking, that if I have to set the HTML for around 100 pictures, there is gonna be a lot alot of HTML code in one document. Each picture would take 6 lines of code.

Comment: For modal..You can move to emodal.js or bootbox.js http://saribe.github.io/eModal/#demo http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ModaliseJS](https://github.com/AlexisTM/modalise.js), which seems to fit your need.

In the head :

```
<script src="js/modalise.js" type="text/javascript">
```

The modal requires no modification (just remove the inline JS)

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="courseModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
      <span class="close"></span>

      <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

      <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
      <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

In your `app.js` file, simply add :

```
var myModal = new Modalise('courseModal', {
      btnsOpen : [document.getElementById('courseImage')]
    }).attach();
```

The handling is automatic, when you will click on the `#courseImage` image, it will trigger the modal. When clicking on the `.close` element into your modal, will close the modal.